# Нужна помощь с непоняткой If else;

Tags: php

Код в следующем:

**1** `<?php if (!empty(res['$pre'])): ?>BLABLA<?php endif; ?>`

**2.** `<?php if (empty(res['$press'])): ?>TEST<?php else: ?>TEST2<?php endif; ?>`

Окей, если пусто $press показывается TEST2, но показывается TEST2 и в 1-ом if.

Почему? Ведь я же закрываю с `<?php endif; ?>` первое.

Comment: Не вижу у вас закрывающейся скобки ифа

Comment: <?php endif; ?>

Comment: if (empty($press) я об этой скобке

Comment: А, я просто здесь это пропустил, но все равно...

Comment: Двоеточие это другая форма объявления и закрытия ифа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что вы пишете 2 `if`, а не `if` `else`. Вы пишете `если` и `если`.

Ваше условие не противоречит друг другу.

```
<?php if (empty($press)): ?>
  TEST
<?php  elseif(empty($press2)): ?>
  TEST2
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Попробовал так, без изменений.

Comment: какое условия пробовали ? 2 пустых

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4447ff16976613a60e5ce7edbc3a53359655096d

Comment: 2 пустых - ТЕСТ
$press не пустой - TEST2
$press2 не пустой - тест2
2 не пустых - ничего не выводится

Comment: ОМГ, я немного перепутал код. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Я разобрался в чем проблема, Ваш ответ ближе к вопросу, спасибо!

Comment: Получилось? может вот так http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04f40d86c628c8bbb7403929a672c7cb1aa29596

Comment: Нет, res не имело к этому отношения. Дело в том, что в первом if где я указал "pre" должен поставить elseif а не закрыть с endif и начать с другим if. Спасибо Вам и другим участникам. :)

Answer (score 0):

Не может TEST2 показывать в обоих случаях,а TEST и TEST2 естественно могут если у вас обе переменные пустые

Comment: Вот и мне странно. Но показывается в обоих случаях. Хотя даже если нет elseif должно показывать там, где именно указан TEST2, потому что TEST1 уже закрыт с <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Обновил вопрос.